# Python: How to print Shortest and Longest word in a text file?

Tags: python, file, input, cpu-word, shortest

I'm trying to make my program print out the shortest and longest word found in a text file. Let's say I type "Pie is delicious" as my block of text. I then type EOF on a line by itself to end the input phase. I typed in option 1 to see the Shortest word and "is" should pop up, but I only get the letter "p" as my output. I get the same result for the second option, which is finding the Longest word, I end up getting the letter "p" when it should be "delicious." I'm using the min and max function to do this by the way.

```
#Prompt the user to enter a block of text.
done = False
textInput = ""
while(done == False):
    nextInput= input()
    if nextInput== "EOF":
        break
    else:
        textInput += nextInput

#Prompt the user to select an option from the Text Analyzer Menu.
print("Welcome to the Text Analyzer Menu! Select an option by typing a number"
    "\n1. shortest word"
    "\n2. longest word"
    "\n3. most common word"
    "\n4. left-column secret message!"
    "\n5. fifth-words secret message!"
    "\n6. word count"
    "\n7. quit")

#Set option to 0.
option = 0

#Use the 'while' to keep looping until the user types in Option 7.
while option !=7:
    option = int(input())

    #Print out the shortest word found in the text.
    if option == 1:
        print(min(textInput, key = len))

    #Print out the longest word found in the text.
    elif option == 2:
        print(max(textInput, key = len))
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not splitting the text into words; instead you are looping over the characters one by one.

Split your text using the [`str.split()` method](http://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) leaving the arguments to the default (splitting on variable-width whitespace):

```
print(min(textInput.split(), key = len))
```